# Undefined Reference issue with C++ and Netbeans

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

I have the following files:

*ListaEnc.hpp*

```
#include "Elemento.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class ListaEnc {

public:
    ListaEnc();
    ~ListaEnc();
...
}

//Implementation:
template<typename T>
ListaEnc<T>::ListaEnc()
{
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

template <class T>
ListaEnc<T>::~ListaEnc() {

}
```

*main.cpp:*

```
#include "ListaEnc.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ListaEnc<int>* teste = new ListaEnc<int>();

    return 0;
}
```

*Poligono.hpp*

```
#ifndef POLIGONO_HPP
#define POLIGONO_HPP

#include "Ponto.hpp"
#include "ListaEnc.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
public:
    //Construtores
    Poligono(ListaEnc<Ponto> pontos, string nome);
    Poligono(const Poligono& orig);
    virtual ~Poligono();

    //Metodos
    string obterNome();
    void adicionarPonto(Ponto);
    ListaEnc<Ponto> obterPontos();
private:
    ListaEnc<Ponto> pontos;
    string nome;
};

#endif  /* POLIGONO_HPP */
```

*Poligono.cpp*

```
#include "Poligono.hpp"



* Poligono::Poligono(ListaEnc<Ponto> pontos, string nome)
{
    this->pontos = pontos;
    this->nome = nome;
}

* Poligono::Poligono(const Poligono& orig) {
}

* Poligono::~Poligono() {
}

//Metodo
string Poligono::obterNome()
{
    return this->nome;
}

ListaEnc<Ponto> Poligono::obterPontos()
{
    return this->pontos;
}

void Poligono::adicionarPonto(Ponto p)
{
    this->pontos.adiciona(p);
}
```

**I get these compile errors on Poligono.cpp:**

> /home/mariana/NetBeansProjects/TrabalhoCG/Poligono.cpp:12: undefined reference to `ListaEnc::~ListaEnc()'

**The destructor for ListaEnc is empty, but is implemented. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?**

**Edit:** Added the implementation of constructor and destructor for ListaEnc. The error appears in the bit of code I added for Poligono.cpp, where ListaEnc is one of the parameters.

**Edit2:** I have added an asterisk to the points in Poligono.cpp where the error appears (The first constructor, second constructor and destructor)

Comment: Please show us the destrucotr, or even better a *small* shortened example where the problem occurs, not some other code.

Comment: That isn't a compile-time error; it is a link-time error. Also, your post doesn't close `ListEnc<>` with `};` before you chose to tell us of your "Implementation of `~ListaEnc<T>`" without bothering to post any of it.  Typo or otherwise, *Post real code that reproduces the actual error*.

Answer (score 1):

Since you posted code that shows

```
#ifndef POLIGONO_HPP
#define POLIGONO_HPP
```

in `Poligono.cpp`, but you don't have the same in `ListaEnc.hpp`, I assume that you are missing include guards in that header?

Depending on what other code is included in `Poligono.cpp`, this could result in the definition of template `ListaEnc` twice. Under C++ standard if you break the one definition rule you may just get a linking error and no other diagnostic message.

So, maybe make sure that there are include guards in `ListaEnc.hpp` ?

If you post more code I will update this answer :)

Edit: Another suggestion, if it is having trouble finding the dtor definition of `ListaEnc`, you might try moving the implementation of it into the class body? This makes it less likely that a typo will cause it to be lost. Since all the code is in the header this really doesn't change anything otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't even realised I forgot the guards! I added them and moved the destructor, but unfortunately the problem persists. I will add more of the code (didn't want to add too much and risk it being confusing)